# How to run a Go http server with nginx

Tags: nginx, go

I have a simple HTTP server written in Go.

In development It works fine but for production, where this server has to handle 100 requests at a time I need a proper web server like nginx.

How can I put it behind nginx?

Comment: Did you try to google? If yes, please add what did you try and where it didnot work?

Comment: I didn't find simple and straight forward solution for this, so posted it here as I am new to these server deployments.

Comment: The stdlib contains a "proper web server" more than capable of handling 100 requests at a time.

Comment: A better question would be "Should I put it behind nginx?" As Danilo says, the answer is probably "no" because the HTTP server in net/http can handle 100 concurrent requests without any problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Danilo I finally understood and I am using Go server it self.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm guessing you need a simple reverse proxy config.

Lets say your go http server is listening on `http://example.com:8080` :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://example.com:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works, Only one thing when I am doing req.remoteAddr I am getting 127.0.0.1 not the correct IP.
Any Idea how to solve it?

Comment: Look for `X-Real-IP` header, we are embedding remoteaddr there.

Comment: I recommend adding `proxy_http_version 1.1;` and `proxy_set_header Connection "";` to enable keepalive. Otherwise you are opening a new connection for every request. See: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#keepalive

Comment: @snap Nice catch, Updated the answer.